# Error Trying to Run DDPLY in Google Colab

Tags: r, dplyr, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab to work on a final project with a set of groupmates. Unfortunately, Colab is not working and I am getting this error. I was able to successfully install and then call the library for the package but when I run the DDPLY code Colab doesn't work.

If anyone can provide insight as to how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Installing Packages]

[image: Running Code]

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with google colab really. You tried to use a function `ddply` from a pack that you didn't load `plyr`. `ddply` is not a `dplyr` function. Make sure to load the correct packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are loading `dplyr` and not `plyr`.
Calling it with either `library(plyr); ddply()` or `plyr::ddply()` should solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

I think ddply is not in dplyr (daft I know!) it is in plyr

So you need

library (plyr)

(And on first use a install.packages("plyr") too)